# it is the jdbc oracle Connectivity for one application, now what is the mysql Connectivity for the same application

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, jdbc

> jdbc.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
>   jdbc.url =jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.4.14:1521:amsprod
>   jdbc.username = licdev
>   jdbc.password = licdev1234

when i am run this program . console panel showing::
1 .java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

2.Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

3. Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: gmslora.ceujuntghskx.ap-south-  1.rds.amazonaws.com

this error.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect Java to a MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database)

Comment: my application previously running on JDBC oracle .now I want to shift MySQL from oracle. if I am changing only JDBC connection code then program is running or change total SQL command...?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration for mysql:

> jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>   jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://172.16.4.14:3306/amsprod
>   jdbc.username = licdev
>   jdbc.password = licdev1234

```
jdbc:mysql://172.16.4.14:  3306/      amsprod
----------------^host-------^port-----^dbname
```

Comment: previously my application configure with oracle database. now I want to switch Mysql from oracle. if i change JDBC property (Configuration for Mysql:) but data base can't  access  .  what is the problem I can't identify .

Comment: do you create a database in mysql or you want to use the same database of oracle in mysql? @BiswajitMondal ?

Comment: ok, then you can make that configuration, do find any problem with this configuration or what @BiswajitMondal

Comment: console panel  WARN    2017-03-14 17:59:16,487 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@6ad93be5 --  Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:458)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
 at

Comment: haha, i'm not a magicien, how can i know this problem, you should to explain that in your question, post your error, post your code, so we can understand what is the problem @BiswajitMondal

Comment: you can edit your question @BiswajitMondal here http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42783545/edit so put all the necessary information there

Comment: my application previously running on JDBC oracle .now  I want to shift MySQL from oracle. if  I am changing only JDBC connection code then program is running or change total SQL command...?